# Use a filter on menu items that have children

Tags: theme-development, filters, sub-menu, dropdown

I have a nested dropdown. On elements that have children, I would like to add a chevron beside the link text. The current HTML looks like this:

```
<ul class="primary-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has- 
    children menu-item-59">
        <a href="#">Europe</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I would like to use an add_filter hook to turn this markup into this:

```
<ul class="primary-menu">
    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has- 
    children menu-item-59">
        <div>
          <a href="#">Europe</a>
          <img src="chevron.svg">
        </div>
        <ul class="sub-menu"></ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I was hoping to find a filter that would return me an array of menu items. If the menu item has the class of 'menu-item-has-children' I would like to change the HTML within the item.

Answer (score 2):

There is indeed a filter, `walker_nav_menu_start_el` will be able to handle it for you!

Take this code for example:

```php
function wpse356896_filter_primary_nav_menu_dropdown( $item_output, $item, $depth, $args ) {

    // Only for our primary menu location.
    if ( empty( $args->theme_location ) || 'primary-menu' !== $args->theme_location ) {
        return $item_output;
    }

    // Add the dropdown for items that have children.
    if ( ! empty( $item->classes ) && in_array( 'menu-item-has-children', $item->classes ) ) {
        return $item_output . '<span class="dropdown"><img src="chevron.svg"></span>';
    }

    return $item_output;
}

add_filter( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', 'wpse356896_filter_primary_nav_menu_dropdown', 10, 4 );
```